# Building an in-app request dialog

Tags: facebook, dialog

Is there a way of building a custom request dialog, and sending the selected userid(s), the app request. I don't want to be using the multi-friend selector form.

Answer (score 0):

This function here should provide you the ability to send a request to a single person.

```
<script>
function sendFriendInvite(message,title,to,data){
    FB.ui({method: 'apprequests', 
          to: to, 
          message: message, 
          title: title,
          data: data
         },
         function(response) {
            if (response && response.request_ids) {
              //Sent!
            } else {
              //Not Sent
            }
        }); 
}
</script>
<a onclick="sendFriendInvite('Here is an invite','Send to Invite to Friend', 123456);">Send request to friend 123456</a>
```